# Convert String to Integer Array

Tags: apex

I have the following code:-

```
string clientNumber = '019224';
List<Integer> integerList = new List<Integer>();
```

How do I iterate through the clientNumber string as if it was an array and load each value into integerList to obtain the following values?

```
integerList[0] = 0
integerList[1] = 1
integerList[2] = 9
integerList[3] = 2
integerList[4] = 2
integerList[5] = 4
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use String **split** in combination with Integer **valueOf**:
Also, extra checks may be added to ensure that each character is valid digit (thanks to [@Novarg](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/12408/novarg))

```
String clientNumber = '019224';
List<Integer> integerList = new List<Integer>();

List<String> client_digits = clientNumber.split('');
for(String s : client_digits) {
    Integer parsed_digit = safeParse(s);
    if (s == null) {
        // invalid character. Do something with it
    } else {
        integerList.add(parsed_digit);
    }
}

//Static Utility method
public static Integer safeParse(String input) {
    Integer result = null;
    try {
        result = Integer.valueOf(input);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // Log here if there is generic logging utility
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: -1, no error management. This will throw an unhandled exception if an initial string contains any non-numerical character

Comment: I like the updated version more :) Changed to +1

Answer (score 3):

oh well, I thought I'll add another possible solution. You can simply use regex and get out all non-numeric characters and then just split and cast it:

```
String testString = 'h3ll0 w0r1d';
String numericString = testString.replaceAll('[^0-9]', '');
List<String> stringList = numericString.split('');
List<Integer> integerList = new List<Integer>();
for (String s : stringList) {
    integerList.add(Integer.valueOf(s));
}
```

Thanks to [kurunve](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/18189/kurunve) for pointing out my mistake in the original post

Comment: Unfortunately, it is impossible to case List<String> to List<Integer> by implicit casting. Unless that, it is a nice way to get digits from input string

Answer (score 3):

You might consider the `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes here:

```
public static List<Integer> getDigits(String input)
{
    List<Integer> digits = new List<Integer>();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile('\\d').matcher(input);
    while (m.find()) digits.add(Integer.valueOf(m.group()));
    return digits;
}
```

It's concise, simple, and avoids any need at all for error handling. I expect it actually performs pretty well comparatively, but I haven't profiled any of these approaches just yet.

Here are a couple test cases just via `Execute Anonymous`:

```
system.debug(getDigits('019224'));
system.debug(getDigits('123-456-7890'));
```

Yields:

> (0, 1, 9, 2, 2, 4)
>   (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0)

Answer (score 1):

You could use different [String methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) for that.

```
String clientNumber = '019224';
List<Integer> integerList = new List<Integer>();

String[] chars = clientNumber.split('');
for(String c : chars){
    if(c.isNumeric()){
        integerList.add(Integer.valueOf(c));
    }
}
System.debug('<<integerList>> '+integerList);
```

> `14:03:25:004 USER_DEBUG [10]|DEBUG|<<integerList>> (0, 1, 9, 2, 2, 4)`

Answer (score -2):

convert string to integer.
your answer here  with example .

Please go through this link:

https://supportsalesforce.blogspot.com/2022/09/convert-string-to-integer.html

let me know if this help you.

Happy to help You!

Thanks,
Anshul sahu

Comment: I think when I came across this answer a couple of days ago, I added a comment like this: "What does your linked blog contribute to the already existing, instructive answers to this 5 year old question? This appears to me as yet another prime example of unconvincing self advertisement." I think Moonpie at the time expressed similar criticism. And then you deleted your answer - just to repost it again! What sense does this make?

Comment: **@FelixvanHove** : Yes, this is *déjà vu*! **Anshul sahu**: SFSE welcomes contributions, and does not mind some self-promotion, but it needs to be within reason, within the rules & guidelines, should only be *portion* of your posts. If you keep posting low quality posts that the community legitimately downvotes you could be disallowed from contributing. Please take [The Tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [Help Center](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help).